# Switching career from Software Engineer to QA Engineer in DevOps

Tags: software-industry, salary, career-development, career-switch

I have just started my career as .NET software engineer with just 2.5 years experience.

Recently one of my Friend suggested to join as QA Engineer in DevOps which has a good pay.

What factors should i consider before switching to QA Engineer ?

Comment: If the question is off topic, then in which site should ask this question ?

Comment: As specific as this question is to the jobs in question and to your personal preferences, it is off-topic. If you could make it more generic, like, "What factors should I consider as decide which career suits me best?," that would be a better question.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere , you are right but i just framed the question to make some decision , there might be some software engineers who are QA engineers ?

Comment: We have no idea whether you would like it, whether you need money to be happy, what you consider "easy" or how the future will turn out, especially predicting that for the very location you might be at that unknown point in the future. That's why your question is going to be closed. We cannot make such a decision for you. It's personal, every single question.

Comment: @nvoigt , you are right.

Comment: @KentA. Thanks, I have edited the question to be more generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some questions to ask yourself:

1. Are you unhappy with your current work? If you are unhappy, what would have to change for you to be happy? Can you make that happen?
2. What are the general activities of the role you are considering? Are they different from your current role? Do you enjoy doing them?
3. What are the career growth opportunities where you currently are? What are they for the role you are considering? Do they match your expectations for your career? (It's ok if these things change over time. That's why people change jobs.)
4. Are there other companies that do these same things? (Can you find another job doing that role if your current company no longer suits your needs?)
5. Is your friend recommending a change because he/she is too timid to tell you that you're not very good at your current role?
6. Is there an opportunity to try out that role for a few months to see whether it suits you better?

There are lots of things to consider. Mostly, what do you want to do? Will that other role fit your goals better than the role you currently have?

Answer (score 1):

You should ask your friends more details about what the job realy is, how's a day at work, details about the environement could also be great. You could dislike an intresting jobs because of a negative workplace.

Basicly it's up to you to list what you like and what you lack at your current job, and compare with what your friend will describe his job like.